# Using the REST API (v2) javascript client on a private namespaced route

Tags: rest-api, backbone

I am using the latest version of the REST API plugin in a project and I've added my routes to a separate namespace (as recommended in [the documentation](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/)). The javascript client included with the API automatically creates models and collections based on the public routes in the `wp/v2` namespace.

Does anyone know if it's possible to extend the built-in client to use a custom namespace, and automatically parse the root endpoint to generate the models and collections for my private API?

Comment: So it appears that there is a variable when the `wp-api.js` file gets read that has a `wpApiSettings.root`that is passed to the `window` object. And you can see that the Backbone collection sets its root [on line 966](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/develop/wp-api.js#L966). So. I would look into where the `apApiSettings` gets passed to this file and see how if there is a hook or filter you can get into.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the [rest url prefix](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L266) you can filter [`rest_url_prefix`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_url_prefix/). But that just changes the `/wp-json/` prefix that every namespace uses.

Trying to modify `wp/v2` means modifying the plugin and that namespace is hard-coded in several places like; [`WP_REST_Post_Statuses_Controller`](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/develop/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-post-statuses-controller.php#L6).

To add your own [custom endpoints](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/), [`register_rest_route`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L32) is in core to do just that.

```
<?php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'your-namespace-here/v1', '/author/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```

You'd have to look more into the [discovery process](http://v2.wp-api.org/guide/discovery/) to see what automatically is built out for your API.

The [controller pattern](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/#the-controller-pattern) example for the [WP REST API Plugin](http://v2.wp-api.org/) should give you a good idea of what can go into a WP REST Controller.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {

    /*
     *      /wp-json/vendor/v1
     */

    $routes = new Slug_Custom_Route();
    $routes->register_routes();

});


class Slug_Custom_Route extends WP_REST_Controller {

    /**
     * Register the routes for the objects of the controller.
     */
    public function register_routes() {
        $version = '1';
        $namespace = 'vendor/v' . $version;
        $base = 'route';
        register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base, array(
            array(
                'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_items' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_items_permissions_check' ),
                'args'            => array(

                ),
            ),
            array(
                'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
                'callback'        => array( $this, 'create_item' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'create_item_permissions_check' ),
                'args'            => $this->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema( true ),
            ),
        ) );
        register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base . '/(?P<id>[\d]+)', array(
            array(
                'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
                'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_item' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'get_item_permissions_check' ),
                'args'            => array(
                    'context'          => array(
                        'default'      => 'view',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
                'callback'        => array( $this, 'update_item' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'update_item_permissions_check' ),
                'args'            => $this->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema( false ),
            ),
            array(
                'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::DELETABLE,
                'callback' => array( $this, 'delete_item' ),
                'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'delete_item_permissions_check' ),
                'args'     => array(
                    'force'    => array(
                        'default'      => false,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ) );
        register_rest_route( $namespace, '/' . $base . '/schema', array(
            'methods'         => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'        => array( $this, 'get_public_item_schema' ),
        ) );
    }

    /**
     * Get a collection of items
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|WP_REST_Response
     */
    public function get_items( $request ) {
        $items = array(); //do a query, call another class, etc
        $data = array();
        foreach( $items as $item ) {
            $itemdata = $this->prepare_item_for_response( $item, $request );
            $data[] = $this->prepare_response_for_collection( $itemdata );
        }

        return new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );
    }

    /**
     * Get one item from the collection
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|WP_REST_Response
     */
    public function get_item( $request ) {
        //get parameters from request
        $params = $request->get_params();
        $item = array();//do a query, call another class, etc
        $data = $this->prepare_item_for_response( $item, $request );

        //return a response or error based on some conditional
        if ( 1 == 1 ) {
            return new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );
        }else{
            return new WP_Error( 'code', __( 'message', 'text-domain' ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create one item from the collection
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|WP_REST_Request
     */
    public function create_item( $request ) {

        $item = $this->prepare_item_for_database( $request );

        if ( function_exists( 'slug_some_function_to_create_item')  ) {
            $data = slug_some_function_to_create_item( $item );
            if ( is_array( $data ) ) {
                return new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );
            }
        }

        return new WP_Error( 'cant-create', __( 'message', 'text-domain'), array( 'status' => 500 ) );


    }

    /**
     * Update one item from the collection
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|WP_REST_Request
     */
    public function update_item( $request ) {
        $item = $this->prepare_item_for_database( $request );

        if ( function_exists( 'slug_some_function_to_update_item')  ) {
            $data = slug_some_function_to_update_item( $item );
            if ( is_array( $data ) ) {
                return new WP_REST_Response( $data, 200 );
            }
        }

        return new WP_Error( 'cant-update', __( 'message', 'text-domain'), array( 'status' => 500 ) );

    }

    /**
     * Delete one item from the collection
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|WP_REST_Request
     */
    public function delete_item( $request ) {
        $item = $this->prepare_item_for_database( $request );

        if ( function_exists( 'slug_some_function_to_delete_item')  ) {
            $deleted = slug_some_function_to_delete_item( $item );
            if (  $deleted  ) {
                return new WP_REST_Response( true, 200 );
            }
        }

        return new WP_Error( 'cant-delete', __( 'message', 'text-domain'), array( 'status' => 500 ) );
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given request has access to get items
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|bool
     */
    public function get_items_permissions_check( $request ) {
        //return true; <--use to make readable by all
        return current_user_can( 'edit_something' );
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given request has access to get a specific item
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|bool
     */
    public function get_item_permissions_check( $request ) {
        return $this->get_items_permissions_check( $request );
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given request has access to create items
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|bool
     */
    public function create_item_permissions_check( $request ) {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_something' );
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given request has access to update a specific item
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|bool
     */
    public function update_item_permissions_check( $request ) {
        return $this->create_item_permissions_check( $request );
    }

    /**
     * Check if a given request has access to delete a specific item
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Full data about the request.
     * @return WP_Error|bool
     */
    public function delete_item_permissions_check( $request ) {
        return $this->create_item_permissions_check( $request );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the item for create or update operation
     *
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Request object
     * @return WP_Error|object $prepared_item
     */
    protected function prepare_item_for_database( $request ) {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Prepare the item for the REST response
     *
     * @param mixed $item WordPress representation of the item.
     * @param WP_REST_Request $request Request object.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function prepare_item_for_response( $item, $request ) {
        return array();
    }

    /**
     * Get the query params for collections
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_collection_params() {
        return array(
            'page'                   => array(
                'description'        => 'Current page of the collection.',
                'type'               => 'integer',
                'default'            => 1,
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint',
            ),
            'per_page'               => array(
                'description'        => 'Maximum number of items to be returned in result set.',
                'type'               => 'integer',
                'default'            => 10,
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'absint',
            ),
            'search'                 => array(
                'description'        => 'Limit results to those matching a string.',
                'type'               => 'string',
                'sanitize_callback'  => 'sanitize_text_field',
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

And when you go directly to the namespace's endpoint `/wp-json/vendor/v1` you should see:

```
{
    "namespace": "vendor\/v1",
    "routes": {
        "\/vendor\/v1": {
            "namespace": "vendor\/v1",
            "methods": ["GET"],
            "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "namespace": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "vendor\/v1"
                    },
                    "context": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "view"
                    }
                }
            }],
            "_links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/vendor\/v1"
            }
        },
        "\/vendor\/v1\/route": {
            "namespace": "vendor\/v1",
            "methods": ["GET", "POST", "GET", "POST"],
            "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": []
            }, {
                "methods": ["POST"],
                "args": []
            }, {
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": []
            }, {
                "methods": ["POST"],
                "args": []
            }],
            "_links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/vendor\/v1\/route"
            }
        },
        "\/vendor\/v1\/route\/(?P<id>[\\d]+)": {
            "namespace": "vendor\/v1",
            "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
            "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "context": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "view"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "methods": ["POST", "PUT", "PATCH"],
                "args": []
            }, {
                "methods": ["DELETE"],
                "args": {
                    "force": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": false
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": {
                    "context": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": "view"
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "methods": ["POST", "PUT", "PATCH"],
                "args": []
            }, {
                "methods": ["DELETE"],
                "args": {
                    "force": {
                        "required": false,
                        "default": false
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "\/vendor\/v1\/route\/schema": {
            "namespace": "vendor\/v1",
            "methods": ["GET", "GET"],
            "endpoints": [{
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": []
            }, {
                "methods": ["GET"],
                "args": []
            }],
            "_links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/vendor\/v1\/route\/schema"
            }
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "up": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/"
        }]
    }
}
```

The two main things that stick out would be:

```
'args' => $this->get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema( WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE )
```

and

```
'args'     => array (
    'force' => array (
        'default' => false,
    ),
),
```

Another example of passing [`$args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/#parameters) to [`register_rest_route`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) which would show up at the namespace root:

```
register_rest_route( "{$root}/{$version}", '/products', array(
        array(
            'methods'         => \WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
            'callback'        => array( $cb_class, 'get_items' ),
            'args'            => array(
                'per_page' => array(
                    'default' => 10,
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
                ),
                'page' => array(
                    'default' => 1,
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
                ),
                'soon' => array(
                    'default' => 0,
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
                ),
                'slug' => array(
                    'default' => false,
                    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_title',
                )

            ),

            'permission_callback' => array( $this, 'permissions_check' )
        ),
    )

);
```

Looking a bit further, [`get_data_for_route`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L1129) is used to collected what ends up in the [discovery endpoints](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L1084) and it's [filterable](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L1110) with [`rest_endpoints_description`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_endpoints_description/) or [`get_data_for_route`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_server/get_data_for_route/). So in theory, if the default doesn't give you what you want, you can use that filter to add your models and/or collections for your private API.

---

So putting it all together and overriding the automatic endpoints:

```
function my_awesome_func( WP_REST_Request $request) {
    return "awesome! " . $request->get_param( 'id' );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'my-thing/v1', '/awesome/(?P<id>\d+)', array (
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );

add_filter( 'rest_endpoints_description', function( $data ) {

    if ( $data[ 'namespace' ] === 'my-thing/v1' ) {

        $data[ 'endpoints' ] = array (
            'foo'     => 'bar',
            'my'      => 'custom-api',
            'awesome' => 'it really is',
        );
    }

    return $data;
} );

/*
 {
    "namespace": "my-thing\/v1",
    "routes": {
        "\/my-thing\/v1": {
            "namespace": "my-thing\/v1",
            "methods": ["GET"],
            "endpoints": {
                "foo": "bar",
                "my": "custom-api",
                "awesome": "it really is"
            },
            "_links": {
                "self": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/my-thing\/v1"
            }
        },
        "\/my-thing\/v1\/awesome\/(?P<id>\\d+)": {
            "namespace": "my-thing\/v1",
            "methods": ["GET"],
            "endpoints": {
                "foo": "bar",
                "my": "custom-api",
                "awesome": "it really is"
            }
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "up": [{
            "href": "http:\/\/example.com\/wp-json\/"
        }]
    }
}
*/
```